# Docker Ubuntu update-alternatives

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I ran into a problem recently where the default compiler, set by `update-alternatives`, is not inherited.

In a base-image I do something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y gcc-4.9 g++-4.9 cmake make gfortran-4.9 make git wget
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 10
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9 10
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gfortran gfortran /usr/bin/gfortran-4.9 10
```

Then in a subsequent image (used with a `FROM base-image`) when I use the compiler, I get a different default version (in this case 5.4).

Is this expected to happen?

I have a workaround where I simply re-do the `update-alternatives` steps at the top of each Dockerfile, but I'm not sure that's the best way to do it.

Comment: you want to chain all your `RUN`s so it should be something like:

`RUN apt update &&
   apt install -y gcc-4.9 g++-4.9 cmake make gfortran-4.9 make git wget &&
   update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 10 &&
   update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9 10 &&
   update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gfortran gfortran /usr/bin/gfortran-4.9 10`

Comment: Try doing the symlink with `CMD` command instead of `RUN` command.